# ZendFramework-1.11.11 and doctrine2-2.2.0-BETA2 issues

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

i m referring tutorial 
http://www.webpixel.gr/blog/zend-framework/integrate-doctrine-2-0-1-with-zend-framework-1-11-x

and i m using
ZendFramework-1.11.11
and
doctrine2-2.2.0-BETA2

there is 3rd step Modify the configuration file
in this strep i cant find out 
application/configs/application.ini in my pc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Bisna](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2) to integrate Zend Framework 1.X + Doctrine 2.X